# How can I code multiple text boxes in html/css/javascript faster?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make 30 different text inputs slightly farther from one another. How could I do this? There are only three below, but I can't just go through and do all 30.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Worksheet</title>
    <style type="text/css">

        .center {
            display: block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            width: 50%;
        }
        input::placeholder{
            color: #d9faa7;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="A.png" class = "center">
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" size="2" style='position:absolute;top:210px;left:389px'>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" size="2" style='position:absolute;top:210px;left:446px'>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" size="2" style='position:absolute;top:210px;left:503px'>

    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `ID` has to be unique. U can have a `class` and in `js` you can loop and append to `form`

Comment: typo: id and name must be unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the id should be unique, so better apply the attribute of class with the same name to all input fields, which can be used to style them.

also using loop in JS you can solve this problem.

```
let form = document.querySelector("form");
let node;
let textInputId;
for(let i=0;i<30;i++)
{
  node = document.createElement('input');
  textInputId= 'fname'+i;
  node.setAttribute('id',textInputId);
  node.setAttribute('type',"text");
  node.setAttribute('name',"fname");
  node.setAttribute('size',"2");
  form.appendChild(node);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be using the input elements to perform a certain action you need to make sure the `id` and the `name` of each of these elements are different.

And on the other hand, about making 30 different text inputs you can try using dynamic text input in the event that you want to enter text with the same `id` and `name` over and over again. Try researching on looping.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the way something appears and just its appearance, just use some simple CSS...

```
input {
    display: block,
    margin: 5px,
}
```

The margin here is 5px, you can change as needed.  In the end, you may decide to go with a better selector, i.e., `<input type="text" ... class="myinputclass">`, then your style selector would be: `.myinputclass` instead of just `input`.